# Como converter pro formato data a string que vem do JSON? (JavaScript MVC C#)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Os dados veem assim:

> `Date(-4735141200000)`

meu for:

```
function (dados) {
    console.log(dados);

    var len = dados.length;
    var txt = "";
    var toDate;
    if (len > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if (dados[i].nome && dados[i].datadenascimento && dados[i].cpf && dados[i].departamento) {

            toDate = new Date(dados[i].datadenascimento);
            console.log(toDate);
            txt += "<tr><td>" + dados[i].nome + "</td><td>" + dados[i].datadenascimento + "</td><td>" + dados[i].cpf + "</td><td>" + dados[i].departamento + "</td><td><a href='javascript:editar(" + dados[i].idfuncionario + ")'>Editar</a></td><td><a href='javascript:deletar(" + dados[i].idfuncionario + ")'>Deletar</a></td></tr>";
       }
    }
    if (txt != "") {
        $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: parece que a data está vindo no formato `Timestamp`. Dê uma olhada nesse link http://stackoverflow.com/a/21523011/2588695

Comment: O que é esperado a partir dessa entrada? Algo como "17/01/2017"?

Comment: Talvez essa função ajude:

`function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {

  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();

}`

`ToJavaScriptDate("Date(-4735141200000)")`

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pela ajuda, mas consegui resolver. Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
jsondata = function (i) {

                    var jsonDate = "/Date(1245398693390)/"; //dados[i].datadenascimento;
                    var re = /-?\d+/;
                    var m = re.exec(jsonDate);
                    var d = new Date(parseInt(m[0]))
                    var day = d.getDate();
                    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                    var year = d.getFullYear();
                    if (day < 10) {
                        day = "0" + day;
                    }
                    if (month < 10) {
                        month = "0" + month;
                    }
                    var date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

                    return date;
                    //tratar data
                }

//entra "/Date(1245398693390)/" e retorna 10/07/1990, por exemplo
```